# pulseaudio-equalizer keeps resetting at startup

Tags: ubuntu, audio, elementary-os, pulseaudio

Every time I start my laptop, pulseaudio-equalizer it's enabled. Even when I disable it (inside the app there's a button to disable it). How can I avoid that?

Moreover, something is resetting my volume to 100% at startup. I believe it has something to do with pulseaudio-equalizer. Can anyone help me to solve this?

I'm using elementaryOS, based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it by running `pulseaudio-equalizer enable` at startup.
For example I add that command to the Startup Application menu.
You should be able to run it at any startup point you find

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a startup shell script that disable pulse-audio equalizer and put the audio volume at the level you want.

To create this you must:

1) create a script, and edit it to your needs. Lets say, you call it pulseaudio.sh

2) copy that script into **/etc/init.d**

3) run the following commands:

```
sudo update-rc.d pulseaudio.sh defaults
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/pulseaudio.sh
```

Comment: Will that make pulseaudio-equalizer unusable? Or I'll be able to open it and enable it?

Comment: You will be able to enable it. It will be disabled when you log in but then can be enabled

Answer (score 0):

Autostart (I tried in KDE) may be wonky because of the order. So there is a way to write the settings into PulseAudio config by running this just once:

```
pulseaudio-equalizer enable-config
```